# radio buttons with simple form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a User model which looks like this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.boolean :admin, default: false
      t.boolean :active, default: false
      t.string :auth_token
      t.string :password_reset_token
      t.datetime :password_reset_sent_at
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

An admin is able to create a user.  How would I make `:admin` and `:active` both part of a radio button group instead of check boxes in my create User form?  I want a new user to be either `:admin`, `:active`, or neither but not both.

Comment: The behavior you want is not usual for radio buttons... Since your user can be either `:admin` or `:active`, why not make it into one field named `status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having that field `status` mentioned in comments, try:

```
f.collection_radio_buttons :status, ['admin','active']
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @juanpastas & @depa -- A cleaner more simplistic approach is to use a single status field.  If for some reason you absolutely must continue with the path you're on then it possible to achieve that in a form.  Lots of moving parts.

In your model:

```
attr_accessor :user_type
```

In your controller create method add a case statement to determine what booleans to change based on user_type's value

```
case params[:user][:user_type]
when "admin"
  user.admin = true
when "active"
  user.active = true
end
```

Create a collection in your view

```
- radio_buttons = [ { :text => 'Active User', :value => :active } , { :text => 'Admin User', :value => :admin } ]
= simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.label  "User Type"
  = f.collection_radio_buttons :user_type, (radio_buttons.collect do |r| [r[:text], r[:value] ] end), :second, :first do |builder|
    = builder.label{builder.radio_button(:class => 'user_options') + builder.text}
  = # Whatever other form fields you want to add
  = f.button :submit, "Sign up"
```